# is it possible to add an oauth2 based user authentication provider to sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication

I should start by saying this is the first time i'm dealing with sharepoint user auth. One of my customer requires users from different identity providers to be able authenticate their users to sharepoint sites within the organization.

Currently we are using the standart AD LDAP auth method but I'm looking for a way to add another auth provider. The information i have is as follows:

They have an oauth2 based identitiy provider system in-house developed software. And they told me they have ldap as authentication provider. I also recieved a postman json file for oauth2 protocol they used. But that doesn't mean much to me at this point.

Please let me know if the above information is enough. If not i'll ask for more information that you might require to provide a solution.

edit: the said ldap integration was for ad user to authenticate through custom oauth2 based  identity provider. At first i thought it would work between oauth2 and sharepoint but that isnt the case.

edit2: would it be possible to create asp.net forms auth page that talks with oauth2 protocols given in json file below? And add that fba to sharepoint auth provider list?

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "7035aaf2-e7c6-40d9-890d-e9f80b5b01dc",
        "name": "OAUTH2Protokol",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "GetAuthentication",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "id": "b6bbbcfe-9521-47ce-9c5f-fa221103559f",
                        "exec": [
                            "var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);",
                            "",
                            "pm.test(\"Access Token recieved\", function(){",
                            "",
                            "    responseBody.has('access_token')",
                            "",
                            "});",
                            "",
                            "pm.environment.set(\"token\", \"Bearer \"+ data[\"access_token\"]);"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "basic": [
                        {
                            "key": "password",
                            "value": "web_secret",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "username",
                            "value": "web_app",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "urlencoded",
                    "urlencoded": [
                        {
                            "key": "username",
                            "value": "**TCKN**",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "grant_type",
                            "value": "password",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "password",
                            "value": "**PASSWORD**",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "scope",
                            "value": "scopenamehere",
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    ],
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://subdomain.domain.gov.tr/oauth/token",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "subdomain",
                        "domain",
                        "gov",
                        "tr"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "oauth",
                        "token"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "GetAuthenticationLDAP",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "id": "b6bbbcfe-9521-47ce-9c5f-fa221103559f",
                        "exec": [
                            "var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);",
                            "",
                            "pm.test(\"Access Token recieved\", function(){",
                            "",
                            "    responseBody.has('access_token')",
                            "",
                            "});",
                            "",
                            "pm.environment.set(\"token\", \"Bearer \"+ data[\"access_token\"]);"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "basic": [
                        {
                            "key": "password",
                            "value": "web_secret",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "username",
                            "value": "web_app",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "urlencoded",
                    "urlencoded": [
                        {
                            "key": "username",
                            "value": "**EMAIL-company**",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "grant_type",
                            "value": "password",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "password",
                            "value": "**EMAIL-PASSWORD**",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "scope",
                            "value": "scopename",
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    ],
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://subdomain.domain.gov.tr/oauth/token",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "subdomain",
                        "domain",
                        "gov",
                        "tr"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "oauth",
                        "token"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "protocolProfileBehavior": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to add a trusted identity provider
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/implement-saml-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-server

Comment: The SharePoint side of your setup would probably be similar to what is found here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate it. I will attempt to impelement a solution by the end of this week. And I will post the results and flag an answer accordingly.

Comment: custom ip following this link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff955607(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

after that use one of these links to make saml work with oauth2 ? 
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Security/Using+OAuth+2.0+from+a+Web+Application+with+SAML+Bearer+Assertion+Flow
https://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/11/19/oauth2-with-saml2.html

am i on the right path?

Comment: I think you just need to add the identity provider to SharePoint.  The rest is a little out of my realm.  I use ADFS as an identity provider, so not sure on the steps for an in house developed one.